# Show there exists a bound sequence ${z_n}$ such that $|f(z_n)|> n$ for all $n$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ be an analytic function satisfying $f(0)=0$
>   and $f(1)=2$. I need to show there exists a bounded sequence ${z_n}$
>   such that $|f(z_n)| >n$ for all $n$.

I know that a non constant entire function assumes all complex values except at most one. But I don't know how to find such a **bounded** sequence.

Comment: I think this problem is false. How can you do this for $f(z) = 2z$.

Comment: This cannot be true, if the sequence $z_n$ is bounded then there is convergent subsequence $z_{k_n}$, i.e. $z_{k_n}\rightarrow z$ so $f(z_{k_n})$ is convergent hence bounded.

Comment: @clark your reasoning seems correct to me. I don't know why this problem is given in my test.

Comment: Perhaps you're recalling incorrectly, and $f$ is defined on the closure of the unit disc, which it maps to itself?

Comment: This question looks very similar to yours, without the bounded condition: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258639/f-mathbb-c-rightarrow-mathbb-c-be-an-arbitrary-analytic-function-satisfying

Comment: @PedroTamaroff if the function is defined on the closure of the unit disc, then $|f|$ is bounded as it is a continuous function on a compact set. Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually in the linked question part $c)$ asks the same thing, however it is a true or false type of a question, which I believe should be the case here as well.

Comment: @clark Hm, yes. What I meant is something like a function that is continuous and analytic on the interior with possible singularities at the boundary.